# National holidays in calendar

Tags: 2013, list, javascript, calendar

I want to exclude national holidays, same as excluding weekends, from working days in Team's vacation calendar.

*Possible idea:*
Create additional list, where I would put national holidays from whole year. If user is going on vacation and national holiday is in period of his absence, I would somehow subtract number of days of that national holiday from his vacation.

**Example:**
John wants to go on holiday from 25.12.2016. - 03.01.2017.
So beside weekends that I excluded from his vacation days, I want to exclude national holidays, like Christmas and New Year.

Any help how to manage this?

Comment: Not possible through Out of box. Need to write custom code to implement this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted in question. Solution was found with additional list.
My colleague, wrote custom js script.
Basically script takes begin and end date in Request for absence list, checks in the Holidays list at Date column if some of those dates are between beginning and ending date. If yes, script reduces number of requested days for each Holiday date that is inside start and end dates.